# Yosemite Safari Favicon

Tags: safari, macos

Anyone know of a way to make Safari show favicons in Yosemite? I was using `Glims` under Mavericks but that no longer works.  I tend to have lots of tabs open and sometimes it's easier to find the proper tab by the favicon rather than the text.

Comment: FYI I've given up and moved back to chrome.  Safari just can't compete when dealing with a large number of tabs.

Comment: @Glorfindel, why mark this as a dupe when it was asked before the other?

Comment: Because that question has a higher score, an upvoted answer and more views (so it's likelier to be found when Googling). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/295232

Comment: About time, they just added it back in the latest macOS beta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Safari 8, favicons no longer show up on the tab bar, to my disappointment.

One solution is to use [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) & [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/). Once installed (see [instructions](http://safaristand.tumblr.com/post/29345453051/how-to-install-safaristand) on the SafariStand site), open the SafariStand settings and check "Show Icon on Tab Bar". This will return favicons to the tabs.

Comment: Thanks but I've just given up, as much as I want to like safari I just can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But a workaround is to use [this Safari Extension](https://github.com/gingerbeardman/favemoji.safariextension) to add emoji to the tabs instead of favicons. For a lot of popular sites there is an emoji that closely matches the favicon or brand!

Comment: While this might be a valuable answer, there's no need to post it [twice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295395/121968). Next time, please [flag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Curious why that extension uses emoji rather than the site's favicon

Comment: Safari doesn't support favicon in tabs (and many other places), it just displays the page title text. Emoji is just text, so I just change the page title. @dstarh

Comment: @MattSephton ahh that makes sense.  Still one of the main reasons I don't like safari

Answer (score -1):

Instead of favicons, try zooming out with a trackpad or a mousepad. It will show you previews of all your open tabs.

Comment: That's hardly a solution to what pretty much every other browser does.  I'm aware of the feature and it's just way too time consuming for normal tab switching