# How to display favicon on my Safari Tab?

Tags: macos, safari, software-recommendation

I want to display favicon on my Safari Tab :

[image]

I am using Yosemite 10.10. 
I've tried [Glims](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims), it doesn't seem to work with Yosemite.

I'm wondering if there are other way around to tweak this natively or with a third party tool.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer from @lid, favicons are no longer showed in Safari 8. They are showed again in the new OS X version El Capitain, which will be released later this year

Comment: Could you indicate where precisely you want these icons to be shown? In the address bar? In each tab by the text? In the Bookmark Bar? Somewhere else? Some combination of the above? Please edit that into your post or add a second image to indicate what the functionality you seek would look like

Comment: In each tab by the text? (Along with where they already are shown too)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with current version of Safari 9 or 9.1.

If, like me, you do really want this feature, please use [Apple Safari feedack form](http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) to send feedback to Apple.

They **do listen** to customer feedback, I can assure you, and when it comes to features like this, the number of requests is essential.

Answer (score 3):

There now is a solution to this: I have created [Faviconographer](https://faviconographer.com/), an app that will overlay Favicons for Safari tabs. It's still a workaround compared to a native Safari feature, but it works surprisingly well.

Answer (score 2):

Safari 10.0.2: favicons are shown when pinning the tab.

This answers your original question, even though is not what you wanted to ask :)

Comment: Oh cool I didn't know about pinning tabs,
also, they appear in bookmarks just realized that even though
I had seen it all along.

Answer (score 2):

As of Safari 12.0 it's now possible. In Preferences, you can now show favicon in the new Tabs settings:

> Show website icons in tabs

[image: Show website icons in tabs]

Answer (score 0):

As of Safari 8, favicons no longer show up on the tab bar, to my disappointment.

One solution is to use [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) & [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/). Once installed (see [instructions](http://safaristand.tumblr.com/post/29345453051/how-to-install-safaristand) on the SafariStand site), open the SafariStand settings and check "Show Icon on Tab Bar". This will return favicons to the tabs.

Comment: Don't use SafariStand - it's a bad solution.
I've tried it and it added many popups to almost any click I did.
I removed it eventually!

Comment: +1 since SafariStand is still compatible with High Sierra / Safari 11: https://github.com/anakinsk/SafariStand/releases/latest

I don't get the issue Yuki reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But a workaround is to use [this Safari Extension](https://github.com/gingerbeardman/favemoji.safariextension) to add emoji to the tabs instead of favicons. For a lot of popular sites there is an emoji that closely matches the favicon or brand!

Answer (score -1):

Just use Glims and install it in "lite" mode.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: It seems like a cheap advertising attempt for Glimpse, which has latest release back in 2013.